# jscrollpage - where are the themes?

Tags: jquery, themes, jscrollpane, skins

I'm running the jscrollpane v2 plugin and so far so good.  I went to the version 1 site and there are 6 different skins...very cool.

On the ver 2 site, there is only one skin (and that's a generous definition)...where are the skins for ver 2?  I assume they're called "themes" now...but still none in site.

Do the ver 1 skins work with ver 2?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one theme called Lozenge: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/themes/lozenge/

It's really easy to build your own though, you should try that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to LekisS's answer, if you do build any extra themes then please submit them through github so that they can be added to the site for other people to use. I would like to make more themes but since jScrollPane is a side project then paying work takes priority. And in the vast majority of cases people use jScrollPane because they already have a specially designed scrollbar that they need to implement...

And no, v1 skins won't work with v2 without some tweaking as the names of the css classes applied have changed...